# Cannot change bash shell in Mac OS X

Tags: bash, shell, osx, homebrew

I'm trying to update `bash` shell on my Mac OS Mavericks.

```
$ brew install bash
$ which -a bash
/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/bash

$ which bash
/bin/bash

$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

In Terminal's preference: Shells open with -> Command (complete path) : `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

But still, I cannot switch to brew-installed bash shell. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 36):

From the `chsh` manual:

> When altering a login shell, and not the super-user, the user may not change from a non-standard shell or to a non-standard shell.  Non-standard is defined as a shell not found in `/etc/shells`.

So you can either run `chsh` as root

```bsh
sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash "$USER"
```

or add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells` to make it a "standard shell"

```bsh
echo /usr/local/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Note that the fact that `which bash` still points to `/bin/bash` does not mean your shell has not been changed, it just means `/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`.